# Why primefaces is not applying validation rules to components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to validate a form using hibernate validations. The hibernate not let the data be included without the required fields, however, no message was sent in primefaces. 
When I sent the form data, they were not included in the database and the screen does not show any error message.

How can i fix that?

xhtml

```
<h:form id="frm" >
    <p:messages />
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputLabel class="form-label required" for="nome" value="Nome" />
        <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{usuarioMB.usuario.nome}">
        </p:inputText>
        <p:message for="nome"></p:message>

        <h:outputLabel class="form-label" for="email" value="E-mail" />
        <p:inputText id="email" type="email"
            value="#{usuarioMB.usuario.email}" />
        <p:message for="email"></p:message>

        <h:outputLabel class="form-label" for="idade" value="Idade" />
        <p:inputText id="idade" value="#{usuarioMB.usuario.idade}" />
        <p:message for="idade"></p:message>

        <h:outputLabel class="form-label" for="cpf" value="CPF" />
        <p:inputText id="cpf" value="#{usuarioMB.usuario.cpf}" />
        <p:message for="cpf"></p:message>

        <h:outputLabel class="form-label" for="ativo" value="Ativo" />
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="ativo"
            value="#{usuarioMB.usuario.ativo}" />
        <p:message for="ativo"></p:message>

        <h:outputLabel class="form-label" for="sexo" value="Sexo" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="sexo" value="#{usuarioMB.usuario.sexo}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Masculino" itemValue="Masculino" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Feminino" itemValue="Feminino" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:message for="sexo"></p:message>

        <h:outputLabel class="form-label" for="situacaoCivil"
            value="Situacao Civil" />
        <p:selectOneRadio id="situacaoCivil"
            value="#{usuarioMB.usuario.situacaoCivil}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Solteiro" itemValue="Solteiro" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Casado" itemValue="Casado" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Divorciado" itemValue="Divorciado" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <p:message for="situacaoCivil"></p:message>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{usuarioMB.salvar}" process=":frm" update=":frm, :table"
        type="submit" icon="ui-icon-check" validateClient="true" />
</h:form>
```

ManagedBeanbean

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name="usuarioMB")
public class UsuarioMB {

    private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

    public String salvar(){
        DaoFactory.getUsuarioDao().save(usuario);
        usuario = new Usuario();

        return "";
    }

    public List<Usuario> findAll(){
        return DaoFactory.getUsuarioDao().findAll();
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

}
```

Entity

```
package edu.fae.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.validator.NotEmpty;
import org.hibernate.validator.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String nome;

    private String email;

    private String sexo;
    private int idade;

    private String cpf;
    private String situacaoCivil;
    private boolean ativo;

    //get set
}
```

faces-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>JavaFlex</display-name>

    <!-- Filtro Hibernate -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>edu.fae.util.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <!-- Filtro que desabilita o cache -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>edu.fae.util.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <!-- Aplica o HibernateFilter em todas as requisições -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- Aplica o Filtro NoCache em todas as requisições *.xhtml -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.TRANSFORM_METADATA</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

exception

```
Ago 17, 2014 9:49:30 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{usuarioMB.salvar}: org.hibernate.validator.InvalidStateException: validation failed for: edu.fae.model.Usuario
javax.faces.FacesException: #{usuarioMB.salvar}: org.hibernate.validator.InvalidStateException: validation failed for: edu.fae.model.Usuario
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at edu.fae.util.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.validator.InvalidStateException: validation failed for: edu.fae.model.Usuario
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.validator.InvalidStateException: validation failed for: edu.fae.model.Usuario
    at org.hibernate.validator.event.ValidateEventListener.validate(ValidateEventListener.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.validator.event.ValidateEventListener.onPreInsert(ValidateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:495)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:301)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at edu.fae.dao.hibernate.UsuarioDaoHibernate.save(UsuarioDaoHibernate.java:44)
    at edu.fae.controllers.UsuarioMB.salvar(UsuarioMB.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 31 more

Ago 17, 2014 9:49:30 PM org.hibernate.AssertionFailure <init>
SEVERE: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in edu.fae.model.Usuario entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at edu.fae.util.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in edu.fae.model.Usuario entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at edu.fae.util.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ago 17, 2014 9:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/introducao] threw exception [org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in edu.fae.model.Usuario entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)] with root cause
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in edu.fae.model.Usuario entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at edu.fae.util.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

libs
[image: libs]

github.: https://github.com/ericrf/poo-sala/tree/master/EntradaDados

Comment: Which Mojarra version?

Comment: @BalusC 2.1.4 version

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your command buttons

```
update=":frm, :table"
```

to

```
update=":frm :table"
```

### My minimal working example:

## page.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name"/>
                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{tests.test.name}"/>
                <p:message for="name"/>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{tests.save}" process="@form" update="@form"/>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

## Tests View-Bean

```
package de.cupofsoftware.carasmo.red.tech.file;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@ViewScoped
@Named
public class Tests {

    private Test test = new Test();

    public Test getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void save() {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

## Test Entity

```
package de.cupofsoftware.carasmo.red.tech.file;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Test {

    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

## Result

[image: Result]

Comment: did this changes but nothing happens

Comment: thanks for your answer man, but it still not working. i think its a lib problem...